# If a suspect supplies a known fraudulent prescription and an officer orders the pharmacist to fill it, does the factual impossibility defense apply?

Tags: criminal-law, constitutional-law

If a suspect supplies a known fraudulent prescription and a police officer orders the pharmacist to fill it, does the factual impossibility defense apply for the suspect? This act was impossible to complete without the police officer.

Comment: The act might have been impossible to complete without the police officer, but the police officer was in fact present, so the crime was in fact committed.

Comment: Isn't impossibility only a defense for attempt? If you committed a crime, it clearly wasn't impossible.

Comment: Shouldn't this only be an attempt since the suspect was unable to commit the crime on their own? The instrument used to commit the crime, fraudulent prescription, failed.

Comment: In what way did the instrument fail?

Comment: @Breakskater That's like saying that if you try to shoot someone but you miss, you're not guilty of attempted murder. The fact that a criminal is bad at crime doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: @cpast That's not at all what I'm saying. I'm saying specifically that the person _is guilty of an attempt_, however the fraudulent prescription  failed, like shooting and missing. So, at this point, the crime is not possible to complete without intervention right?

Comment: @phoog the instrument failed because it was discovered to be false thus ineffective for receiving a controlled substance from any pharmacy

Comment: @Breakskater Did they commit the actual crime (excuses and justifications aside, did they literally do the thing prohibited by the law)? Then it was obviously not impossible. Impossibility means something *cannot be done*. It doesn't mean "can't be done without a police reverse sting," it means "cannot be done at all." It refers to things like attempted murder with a voodoo doll.

Comment: @cpast I see. Yes, the crime was possible to commit so it rules out the impossibility defense, unfortunately. I was hoping the impossibility defense meant that a suspect alone could not commit the crime in a given context. Thanks for the exaplanation

Answer (score 3):

For the record, factual impossibility is rarely a defense to a crime. In *United States v. Thomas* the court decided that men who believed they were raping a drunken unconscious women were guilty of attempted rape, even though the woman was dead at the time.

In this case there is no facts that made the offense impossible to commit. The suspect clearly submitted a false prescription and obtained the drugs he or she wished to obtain. There is no impossibility. Instead the police officer, as the saying goes, has the suspect "dead to rights".

This is not legal advice. Consult an attorney for that.